# How to make Left slip menu bar using SWRevealViewController in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

Here my code for right slid menu

```
if revealViewController() != nil {
        revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 62
        menuButton.target = revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

        revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth = 150
        view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

    }
```

[image]

Comment: this is your Left reveal, whats your question now

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to show it in the right slid. Please help me